# How do I type html in a markdown file without it rendering?

Tags: html, markdown

I want to type the following sentence in a markdown file: she says `<h1>` is large. I can do it in StackOverflow with three backticks around h1, but this doesn't work for a .md file. I've also tried a single backtick, single quote, double quote, hashtags, spacing, `<code>h1</code>` and everything else I could think of. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would think it depends on the specific renderer that you're using. For example, the legacy C# Markdown library (based on Stack Overflow's) appears to have [some options](https://github.com/hey-red/Markdown/blob/master/src/Markdown/MarkdownOptions.cs) related to what you want.

Comment: standard markdown allows single backticks. if that doesn't work with your renderer, then its a problem with the renderer

Comment: It usually is a really good idea to read the documentation of the tools one uses....

Comment: I'm using the renderer from Github. I can't find where it specifies how to do this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can escape the `<` characters by replacing them with `&lt;`, which is the HTML escape sequence for `<`. You're sentence would then be:

```
she says &lt;h1> is large
```

As a side note, the [original Markdown "spec"](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autoescape) has the following to say:

> However, inside Markdown code spans and blocks, angle brackets and ampersands are always encoded automatically. This makes it easy to use Markdown to write about HTML code. (As opposed to raw HTML, which is a terrible format for writing about HTML syntax, because every single < and & in your example code needs to be escaped.)

...which means that, if you're still getting tags when putting them in backticks, whatever renderer you're using isn't "compliant" (to the extent that one can be compliant with that document), and you might want to file a bug.

Answer (score 17):

Generally, you can surround the code in single backticks to automatically escape the characters. Otherwise just use the HTML escapes for < `&lt;`and > `&gt;`.

i.e.

```
she says &lt;h1&gt; is large or she says `<h1>` is large
```

Answer (score 3):

A backslash (`\`) can be used to escape `<` and `>`.

Ex: she says <h1> is large

P.S. See this answer's source by clicking `Edit`.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to escape the `<` and `>` characters.

Comment: and it's also the most readable if someone decides to just read the pre-rendered version